# JQuery live submit event not call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The code:**

```
$("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").live("change",function(){

    $("#pitch_image_path_form").live("submit",function(e){
        alert("sdfdsf");
            this.submit();

        });


    });
```

Now change event is called but then not call the form submit event.

The live submit event is not being called.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live` is no longer available in jQuery 1.9 or newer.

Comment: @mooseman read the live change event is called successfully but not call live submit event.

Comment: It seems to me that you're trying to call the submit method and not to assign the handler

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form or do you just want to bind an event handler whenever `#pitch_image_path_browseiser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dear renishkhunt please try this code. this is help fully for me.

```
$("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").live("change",function(){
    $("#pitch_image_path_form").ajaxSubmit({ success: function(){ 
            alert("sdfdsf");
     } });
});
```

please check this link [this is tutorial](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Answer (score 1):

The code you have will attach to the `submit` event when the change event fires. It will not trigger any of the events

you'd need to trigger the submit directly instead

```
$("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").live("change",function(){
    $("#pitch_image_path_form")[0].submit();});
```

if you wish to do something on the submit event you could add an event to the submit. Note that that event fires before information is sent to the server. There's no event for when the submit is done, since submission reloads the page (or another page)

```
 $(function(){
     $("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").live("change",function(){
        $("#pitch_image_path_form")[0].submit();
     });

      $("#pitch_image_path_form").live("submit",function(){
         //do what ever you need to do here
         //$.post(url);
      });
  });
```

Comment: you are write dear thank you. now i want to send post link when submit is return.

Comment: @renishkhunt The aboce is working but it might not do what you want it to but without explaining what you want it to do more specifically I can't help you

Answer (score 0):

I made some change because in your code, you attach the `submit` event each time the `#pitch_image_path_browseiser` change. , tell me if it fix your issue :

```
$("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").die('change').live('change',function(){

$("#pitch_image_path_form").unbind('submit').bind("submit",function(e){
    alert("sdfdsf");
        //this function is already called ONLY when form is submitted...
       // this.submit();

    });

});
```

But in this case, you have to wait the form to be submitted... If you want to submit the form, use or add :

```
$("#pitch_image_path_form").submit();
```

So if i understand that you wan't to do, I think the good way is : (I kept the `live` call)

```
 $("#pitch_image_path_form").unbind('submit').bind("submit",function(e){
    alert("sdfdsf");
});
$("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").die('change').live('change',function(){
   $("#pitch_image_path_form").submit();
});
```

Comment: i try but this code is not working the submit event is not submit form. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `.live()` is not available since jQuery 1.9. what version are you running ?

anyway, use instead `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('change', '#pitch_image_path_browseiser', function() { 
    $(document).on('submit', '#pitch_image_path_form', function(e){
       alert("sdfdsf");
       $("#pitch_image_path_form").submit();
    });
});
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this :

```
$("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").live("change",function(){
    $("#pitch_image_path_form").submit();
});
```

Which means when "change" is triggered, submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Just call $("#pitch_image_path_form").submit() instead of the second .live

But you'll need to specify the .live method elsewhere

```
$("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").live("change",function(){
    $("#pitch_image_path_form").submit();
});

$("#pitch_image_path_form").live("submit",function(e){
    alert("sdfdsf");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.submit()` is being called when it has been submitted... I'm thinking you want to trigger it to show the alert

try:

```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").die('change').live('change',function(){
    $("#pitch_image_path_form").unbind('submit').bind("submit",function(e){
        alert("sdfdsf");
    });
  });

  $("#pitch_image_path_form").trigger('submit');

});
```

Comment: well I'm writing it from memory a bit but I suspect if it doesn't work you should check your element ids